# StackOverflowError when calling RuleGrammar.listRuleNames() using Sphinx

Tags: java, stack-overflow, cmusphinx, jsapi

I am using Sphinx to parse grammar files.

I have a function that loads all the grammar files. This function is called at the start of the program and every time the user requests a `reload`. When called initially it works. The `StackOverflowError` arises when subsequent calls are made to this function. The particular line in the function that causes the error is the `gram.listRuleNames()` line, specifically the method of `RuleGrammar listRuleNames()`.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is occurring?

The function:

```
BaseRecognizer recognizer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    recognizer = new BaseRecognizer();
    recognizer.allocate();
    LoadAllGrammars();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    LoadAllGrammars();
    recognizer.deallocate();
}

private static void LoadAllGrammars() throws IOException {
    RuleGrammar[] gramss = recognizer.listRuleGrammars();
    for (RuleGrammar rg : gramss) {
        recognizer.deleteRuleGrammar(rg);
    }

    recognizer.commitChanges();

    RuleGrammar gram = null;

    URL dir = new File("grams").toURI().toURL();

    gram = recognizer.loadJSGF(dir, "main", true, true, null);

    String[] names = gram.listRuleNames();

    //the rest of the code in the function is irrelevant to the question
}
```

The error:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-23" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.newKeyIterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRuleGrammar.listRuleNames(BaseRuleGrammar.java:266)
    at com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.loadFullQualifiedRules(BaseRecognizer.java:958)
    at com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.loadImports(BaseRecognizer.java:938)
    at com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.loadFullQualifiedRules(BaseRecognizer.java:980)
```

After some debugging I have noticed that `recognizer.deleteRuleGrammar(rg)` isn't deleting the old grammars.

I have narrowed it down to the line `loadJSGF()` which when called twice results in the `StackOverflowError`. I would think it has something to do with the recognizer not deleting the old grammars.

Comment: I am guessing its the for loop which is creating **a lot of** `Rule` object.

Comment: It works the first time the function is run, also according to the error (and the lack of lines being printed) it doesn't even get to the loop.

Comment: Please provide the sample code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I removed all references to my GrammarParser class and added a main function so you can reproduce my problem.

Comment: HashMap is not thread safe; are you doing something concurrently? I do see no sign here, but possible. More likely you constructed something recursively in your data in your class.